# Configuring a DHCP server with VLAN on a switch

Tags: networking, cisco, dhcp

I have a problem while configuring a switch, I want to create a VLAN and to activate the DHCP server and so all switch ports associated to this VLAN will receive automatically an IP address from the DHCP server.

So I want to ask you if this is possible ? and If 'yes', how can I dot it ? because I didn't found the appropriates commands (cisco or d-link) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, of course it's possible

take a look at this, i think it's what u want :

[Vlan's and DHCP](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/12345)

Here is what u should do :

```
ip dhcp pool pool1
network 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 10.10.1.1 
dns-server what.ever.ip.itis
!
ip dhcp pool pool2
   network 10.10.2.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.10.2.1 
   dns-server what.ever.ip.itis2
vlan 10
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
vlan 20
ip address 10.10.2.1 255.255.255.0
```

you must define two pools( or more ), and give them same range IP as u gave to your VLANs ... it will work ...

And you should also exclude ip addresses that the router uses (.1 in this example).